# How do you make a normal user an admin user in a Hyrax app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started up my first Hyrax application in development mode and am trying to turn my first user into an admin so I can see the admin dashboard and settings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user you want to make an admin is in `config/role_map.yml` under `development:admin`. For example:

```
development:
  archivist:
    - archivist1@example.com
  admin:
    - admin_user@example.com

test:
  archivist:
    - archivist1@example.com
    - archivist2@example.com
    - leland_himself@example.com
  admin_policy_object_editor:
    - archivist1@example.com
  donor:
    - donor1@example.com
    - leland_himself@example.com
  researcher:
    - archivist1@example.com
    - researcher1@example.com
  patron:
    - patron1@example.com
    - leland_himself@example.com

production:
  # Add roles for users here.
```

Then bounce your rails server and refresh your dashboard.